# Nested Vue router-view transition not reacting when navigating

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Here is code example:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jypnkue/

The *transition v-on:enter="enter"* for the nested view is not called when also the main router-view is transitioning.

```
<router-view ref="nestedView" v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition v-on:enter="enter">
    <component :is="Component"/>
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

I would like both animations being called simultaneously.

Using Vue 3 and Vue Router 4 release candidate/beta.

Comment: The reason seems to be that you are directly routing from `Home` to `nestedView`, in which case the inner transition doesn't happen because it's mounted firstly to the parent and then mounted to dom. If you add another `Parent` link and then route from `parent` to `nestedView`, you will see that the `enter` event is fired: https://jsfiddle.net/g02tdvko/

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is correct, however, there are many cases where a user might navigate directly to the nestedView, and my desired effect is that both router-views should transition. I have been trying to force the mounting of the nestedView to the DOM after the main transition is triggered, but it didn't work https://jsfiddle.net/bpetg71a/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 'appear' to the router fixes it:

```
<router-view ref="nestedView" v-slot="{ Component }" appear>
  <transition v-on:enter="enter">
    <component :is="Component"/>
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27qae5zj/1/